# How can I remove existing word from one column to another?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, scala, apache-spark, unix

I have a trouble removing string value that exists in different column. Column 3 is my expected result. See example below
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried regex and replace

Comment: can you explain the logic for result, with more examples?

Comment: Please replace the image by text. And make the result a new code block, now I am not sure what you want (look for second column with a tab as a filed sep, and in that column look for the third field using | as sep and only display that field?) And show your failed command, that might show some requirements that slow readers might miss in your explanation

Answer (score 2):

This answer work only if you have `column 1 and column 2` string value with pipe `(|)` delimiter.

Now let consider having following data in your data frame :

```
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(("WER|RYH|YYU","WER|RYH|TTT|YYU"))).toDF("col1","col2")

df show

+-----------+---------------+
|       col1|           col2|
+-----------+---------------+
|WER|RYH|YYU|WER|RYH|TTT|YYU|
+-----------+---------------+
```

Now we need to create UDF for column 3 as below :

```
val findDiff = udf{(s1 : String, s2: String)=> 
     val first = s1.split("\\|").diff(s2.split("\\|"))
     if(first.isEmpty) s2.split("\\|").diff(s1.split("\\|")).mkString else first.mkString
     }
```

So above UDF gives the result in both column 1 and 2 using interchange both values

and use this UDF as below

```
df.withColumn("col3",findDiff($"col1",$"col2")).show

+-----------+---------------+----+
|       col1|           col2|col3|
+-----------+---------------+----+
|WER|RYH|YYU|WER|RYH|TTT|YYU| TTT|
+-----------+---------------+----+
```

So this give us expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below logic to gain the missing values.

Below code explodes the values and gives out unique id to a column.

```
val df = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("****").select(split('c1,"\\|").as("cs1"),split('c2,"\\|").as("cs2")).withColumn("id",monotonicallyIncreasingId).select(explode('cs1).as("css1"),'cs2,'id).select('css1,explode('cs2).as("css2"),'id)
```

Register it to a temp table and run below query.

```
spark.sql("""select distinct * from (select case when c.css1 is null then c.id2 when c.css2 is null then c.id1 else null end as id,case when c.css1 is null then c.css2 else c.css1 end as c3 from (select a.css1,b.css2,a.id as id1, b.id as id2 from data a FULL OUTER JOIN data b ON a.css1 = b.css2 and a.id = b.id) c) d where d.id is not null""").show
```

This gives out missing values in particular rows. Utilise this to achieve the desired result.